# Java error while trying to print a variable initialized within if

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to print a String which was initialized within the if-else statement. But I'm having an error regarding dateStr may not have been initialized in the last line. Any suggestion?
This is the code:

```
int currentDay = LocalDateTime.now().getDayOfMonth();
int currentMonth = LocalDateTime.now().getMonthValue();
int currentYear = LocalDateTime.now().getYear();
String dateStr;
if (currentDay < 10 && currentMonth < 10){
    dateStr = "0" + currentDay + "/0" + currentMonth + "/" + currentYear;
} else if (currentDay < 10 && currentMonth >= 10) {
    dateStr = "0" + currentDay + "/" + currentMonth + "/" + currentYear;
} else if (currentDay >= 10 && currentMonth >= 10){
    dateStr =  currentDay + "/" + currentMonth + "/" + currentYear;
}
System.out.println(dateStr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an `else` case without which your `String` *`may not have been initialized`*.

Otherwise initialize it to a default value, such as `null` or an empty string:

```
String dateStr = "";
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked

Answer (score 3):

You did not initialize `dateStr` variable and the compiler is throwing the error because there is a **possibility that none of your `if` blocks will be executed at runtime** (because of the values for `currentDay`, `currentMonth`, the conditions are NOT met), **then the `dateStr` variable is not pointing to anything**, which is causing the error, so, there are two options to solve the issue:

**Option (1):** Initialize the `dateStr` variable

```
String dateStr = null;
```

**Option (2):** Add an `else` condition as shown below:

```
    if (currentDay < 10 && currentMonth < 10){       
        dateStr = "0" + currentDay + "/0" + currentMonth + "/" + currentYear;
    } else if (currentDay < 10 && currentMonth >= 10) { 
        dateStr = "0" + currentDay + "/" + currentMonth + "/" + currentYear;
    } else if (currentDay >= 10 && currentMonth >= 10){ 
        dateStr =  currentDay + "/" + currentMonth + "/" + currentYear;
    } else {
        dateStr="INVALID";
    }
```

I strongly suggest you make a practice to **always initialize the local variables** properly. The other point that you might be interested in is that you will NOT face this issue for **class/instance variables which will automatically get initialized to default values** (unlike local variables for which you need initialize).

Answer (score 2):

initialize it to an empty string first:

String dateStr = "";

Answer (score 2):

```
String dateStr= null;
```

That is because, what if none of the condition is fulfilled.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you must initialize this variable into the context of function and use into the `else` and `if`, like this:

```
String dateStr = "";
if (currentDay < 10 && currentMonth < 10){
    dateStr = "0" + currentDay + "/0" + currentMonth + "/" + currentYear;
} else if (currentDay < 10 && currentMonth >= 10) {
    dateStr = "0" + currentDay + "/" + currentMonth + "/" + currentYear;
} else if (currentDay >= 10 && currentMonth >= 10){
    dateStr =  currentDay + "/" + currentMonth + "/" + currentYear;
}
System.out.println(dateStr);
```

As you did it, you only are initialized the variable into the context of `if` or `else if` and that is the reason that compiler detect that the variable `dateStr`is not initialized into the context of function.

Answer (score 1):

You declared a variable but didn't initialize it. To initialize you need to do this

```
    String datestr = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

not all your paths add a value to the variable, do this

```
...
 else if (currentDay >= 10 && currentMonth >= 10){ 
        dateStr =  currentDay + "/" + currentMonth + "/" + currentYear;
    } else {
        dateStr = "it didn't work!";
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

As @JeanLogeart stated, adding an `else` condition would remove your error.
Although, I would create a padding function to mitigate the need for the conditionals like so:

```
private String padThatNumber(int number, int numberOfDigits){
    StringBuilder sb= newStringBuilder();
    sb.append(Integer.toString(number));
    while(sb.length()<numberOfDigits){
        sb.insert(0, "0");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens when currentDay >=10 && currentMonth<10?? Make sure to check all cases. Also try initializing the street to empty. String s ="";